# How do neuroblastoma cells divide? Is it via mitosis?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, cell-culture

My name is Daniel and I'm 17 years old. I am currently designing a study to investigate compounds that potentially increase the replication of neural cells. I will be using neuroblastoma cells and creating different water based media to apply to these cells. I don't however understand how they divide. Is it via mitosis or do they replicate in a different way as they are essentially, cancer cells.

Comment: don't cancer cells divide by mitosis as well - it's just not as regulated as in a normally dividing cell

Comment: I thought it was mitosis but it was increased. I could calculate the mitotic index of control groups with no media applied to it and then calculate the mitotic index of the cells where the compunds have been added? How reliable would this be as evidence?

Comment: you're correct (as far as I know) - cancer cells divide similar to other cells... it's just much more rapid... what is your question that you're trying to ask with your experiment? A well-focused questions is of paramount importance prior to conducting a well-controlled study.

Comment: Pathologists do indeed calculate mitotic indices to determine how rapidly the cells are dividing compared to normal cells, but you need to establish what's normal first. That is your control group.

Comment: It isn't really an closed question that I'm trying to answer, it is investigating which substances can increase the rate of cell division. The substances have been decided by reading about speculation surrounding these substances as to whether they actually have the potential to do this. If you want to hear more about a method, I'd be happy to share my ideas. Hopefully if there are any flaws, you can help rectify them as I am only an A-level student at the minute.